# How to define Commitizen adapter when using "npx git-cz"?

Tags: git, npm, commit, npx, commitizen

I am trying to adopt a **conventional commits** like standard to my projects. While searching for linters and other automation tools I stumbled upon [commitizen](https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli).
I want to use it in my project without installing it locally neither globally using the NPX with the command `npx git-cz`.

- How to define the adapter using this approach? (without installing it locally or globally)
- What is the default adapter used by Commitizen when on NPX? (Couldn't find in their documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue in commitizen](https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli/issues/564).

If the repository is not commitizen friendly, running `npx git-cz` will install and use the [streamich/git-cz](https://github.com/streamich/git-cz) adapter.

I think this works only because of package name collisions, and do not think you can configure a different adapter this way.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've come to making my repository "commitizen-friendly" without a local package.json is the following --

Define a [.czrc](https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli#making-your-repo-commitizen-friendly) file in the repository

```
{
  "path": "cz-conventional-changelog",
  "maxLineWidth": 72
}
```

And when using npx, explicitly set the commitizen package:

```
npx --package cz-conventional-changelog --package commitizen -- cz
```

Or if your users can install commitizen globally (e.g. `npm install -g commitizen cz-conventional-changelog`) then this becomes

```
git cz
```

This *seems* to work for me. Hopefully I'm not missing something.

**EDIT**
I did miss something. Both recommendations require the adapters to also be specified or installed. Amended the above.